Why is my laplace transform of unit step functions wrong?
$ f(t) = \cases{        0       & $0 \le t < 5$ \cr
                 (t-5)/5 & $5\le t\le 10$ \cr
                        1       & $t \ge  10$ }
$
in terms of step functions,
$f(t) = \frac{(u_5(t)(t-5) - u_{10}(t)(t-10)%)}{5} $
When I take laplace of both sides I get
$\mathcal{L}[f(t)] = \frac{e^{-5s}\mathcal{L}[f(t)]}{5} - \frac{e^{-10s}\mathcal{L}[f(t)]}{5} $.
Dividing both sides by $\mathcal{L}[f(t)]$ is clearly the wrong answer. The correct answer is
$\mathcal{L}[f(t)] = \frac{e^{-5s}\ - e^{-10s}}{5s^2} $
Could someone explain where I went wrong here? I just followed this formula given

to take laplace of both sides.

Your error is the inappropriate double use of the same symbol $f$. Correctly written it should be
$$
\mathcal{L}[f(t)] = \frac{e^{-5s}\mathcal{L}[g(t)]}{5} - \frac{e^{-10s}\mathcal{L}[g(t)]}{5}
$$
where $g(t)=t$ and $\mathcal{L}[g(t)]=\frac1{s^2}$.
The $f$ of the transformation rule has nothing to do with the $f$ of your specific function. Before mixing these two facts, you need to rewrite one of them with a different symbol, for instance by replacing the $f$ of the rule with the next unused letter $g$.

$$
\hat f(s) =\frac{e^{-5 s}-e^{-10 s}}{5 s^2}
$$
is the Transform for  $ f(t) = \cases{        0       & $0 \le t < 5$ \cr
                 (t-5)/5 & $5\le t\le 10$ \cr
                        1       & $t \ge  10$ }
$
The correct Transform for  $ f(t) = \cases{        0       & $0 \le t < 5$ \cr
                 (t-5)/5 & $5\le t\le 10$ \cr
                        0       & $t \ge  10$ }
$
is:
$$
\hat f(s)=\frac{1-e^{-5 s} (5 s+1)}{5 s^2}
$$
and is obtained as follows:
Calling $g(t) = \frac t5(u(t)-u(t-5))$ we have $\hat g(s) = \int_0^5 e^{-s t}\frac t5 dt = \frac{1-e^{-5 s} (5 s+1)}{5 s^2}$but we need $\hat f(s) = e^{-5s}\hat g(s)$.

That was a mistake, the function was supposed to be the one you suggested.
I'm just not sure whats wrong with the method I used.

Use directly the Laplace transform $\int_5^{10}e^{-s t}\frac{t-5}{5}dt + \int_{10}^{\infty} e^{-s t}dt$. and $\int_{10}^{\infty} = \int_0^{\infty} -\int_0^{10}$.
